# OCaml: Stack_overflow exception in pervasives.ml

Tags: debugging, ocaml, stack-overflow

I got a `Stack_overflow` error in my OCaml program lately. If I turn on backtracing, I see the exception is raised by a "primitive operation" "pervasives.ml", line 270. I went into the OCaml source code and saw that line 270 defines the function `@` (i.e. list append). I don't get any other information from the backtrace, not even where the exception gets thrown in my program. I switched to bytecode and tried `ocamldebug`, and it doesn't help (no backtrace generated).

I thought this is an extremely weird situation. The only places in my program where I used a list is (a) building a list containing integers 1 to 1000000, (b) in-order traversing a RBT and putting the result into a list, and (c) printing a list of integers containing ostensibly 1000000 numbers. I've tested all functions and none of them contain could an infinite loop, and I thought 1000000 isn't even a huge number. Moreover, I've tried the equivalent of my program in Haskell (GHC), Scala and SML (MLton), and all of those versions worked perfectly and in a reasonably short amount of time. So, the question is, what could be going on? Can I debug it?

Comment: well, without seeing code, it's hard to tell, but the problem maybe comes from the fact that you're using the (@) operator to append an element at the end of a list, which has a terrible complexity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@` operator is not tail-recursive in the OCaml standard library,

```
let rec ( @ ) l1 l2 =
  match l1 with
    [] -> l2
  | hd :: tl -> hd :: (tl @ l2)
```

Thus calling it with large lists (as the left argument) will overflow your stack.

It could be possible, that you're building your list by appending a new element to the end of the already generated list, e.g.,

```
let rec init n x = if n > 0 then init (n-1) x @ [x] else []
```

This has time complexity `n^2` and will consume `n` slots in the stack space.

Concerning the general question - how to debug such stack overflows, my usual recipe is to reduce the stack size, so that the problem is triggered as soon as possible before the trace is bloated, e.g.,

```
OCAMLRUNPARAM=b,l=1024 ocaml ./test.ml
```

If you're compiling your OCaml code to the native code, then you need to pass the `-g` option to the compiler, so that it can produce backtraces. Also, in the native execution, the size of the stack is controlled by the operating system and should be set using the corresponding mechanism of your OS, for example with `ulimit` in GNU/Linux, e.g., `ulimit -s 1024`.

As a bonus track, the following `init` function is tail recursive and will have `O(N)` time complexity and will take `O(1)` stack space:

```
let init n x =
  let rec loop n xs =
    if n = 0 then xs else loop (n-1) (x :: xs) in
  loop n []
```

The idea is to use an accumulator list and build the list in the heap space.

If you don't like thinking about tail-recursiveness then you can use Janestreet Base library (or Core), or Batteries library. They both provide tail-recursive versions of the `init` function, as well as guarantees that all other functions are tail-recursive.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP didn't compile with `-g`. Maybe you should add a mention to it in your (otherwise very complete) post.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried `-g` which didn't help :-) The problem is indeed `@`. I switched to Core and the problem got fixed instantly.

Answer (score 0):

List functions in the standard library are optimised for small lists and are not necessarily tail-recursive; with the partial justification that lists are not an efficient data structure for storing large amount of data (note that Haskell lists are lazy and thus are quite different than OCaml eager lists).

In particular, if you get a stackoverflow error using `@`, you are quite probably implementing an algorithm with a quadratic time-complexity due to the fact that `@`'s complexity is linear in the size of its left argument.

They are probably far better data structure than list for your problem, if you want iteration the sequence library or any other forms of iterator would be far more efficient for instance.

With all the caveat stated before, it is relatively straightforward to redefine tail-recursive but inefficient version of the standard library function, e.g. :

```
 let (@!) x y = List.rev_append (List.rev x) y
```

Another option is to use the `containers` library or any of the extended standard libraries (batteries or base essentially): all of those libraries reimplement tail-recursive version of list functions.